# rotate a .gif image on google maps api v3?

Tags: javascript, image, google-maps-api-3, rotation, gif

I find lots of answers on this question but not one that works when using .gif images and not markers.  To use .gif images (and also animated gifs) I use code (which works)

```
var image = {
  url: 'img/RedFlashYacht.gif',
  size: new google.maps.Size(75, 75),
  origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
  anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32),
  scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50, 50)
};
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: pos , 
    map: map,
    icon: image,
    store_id: mkrID,
    optimized: false
});
```

//for anyone who has not used .gif, the line 'optimized: false'  is critical

What I want to do now is rotate the gif image (to a specified angle, not a constant rotate [that I can do as animated gif]). Dispite setting the ID for the image with 'store_id: mkrID,'   var mkrID being previously created, and I can read it back with code  marker.get('store_id') so I know it's been set.  I cannot access the image with document.getElementById.   nor can I get any of the google maps API rotate eample code to work either.  Examples I find seem to be for v2 or relate to google maps own markers, not custom images using a gif.

Has anyone been able to rotate a gif image in a google map?

Comment: Thanks for the `optimized` parameter. Made my day.

Answer (score 9):

The "store_id" property of the marker doesn't give you access to the DOM element which contains the image. If you have a unique icon for each marker, you can grab it using its URL with JQuery, then apply a CSS transform to it:

```
$('img[src="http://www.geocodezip.com/mapIcons/boat-10-64.gif"]').css({
  'transform': 'rotate(45deg)'
});
```

**Note:** this will only work for markers with `optimized: false`

- [proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/ehzn7v3u/6/)
- [proof of concept fiddle rotating a .png image](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/dc9v0spu/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.47949, -122.083168),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var image = {
    url: 'http://www.geocodezip.com/mapIcons/boat-10-64.gif',
    size: new google.maps.Size(75, 75),
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32),
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50, 50)
  };
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter(),
    map: map,
    icon: image,
    store_id: "mkrID",
    optimized: false
  });
  var rotationAngle = 10;
  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
    setInterval(function() {
      $('img[src="http://www.geocodezip.com/mapIcons/boat-10-64.gif"]').css({
        'transform': 'rotate(' + rotationAngle + 'deg)'
      });
      rotationAngle += 10;
    }, 1000);
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Interesting.  At the moment all images will be the same (but at different deg of rotation), so for this to work I could create copies of same gif with differing names. A bit of a clumsy way, but doable so long as there are not a lot of images to be placed on the map

Comment: adding a GET variable (that does nothing), like `nonclumsy.gif?1` / `nonclumsy.gif?2` / `nonclumsy.gif?3` will help you duplicating gifs. still not very nice, as browsers will download all seperatly, but if it's not thousands of them...

Comment: can rotate from store_id? duplicate image is not good if on map load more than 10 marker

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is to use [Custom Overlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/customoverlays).

```
    .
    .
    var overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
    overlay.draw = function() {
        this.getPanes().markerLayer.id = 'markerLayer';
    }
    overlay.setMap(map);
    .
    .
    var deg = 270;
    document.querySelector("#markerLayer img").style.transform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
    .
```

See this [demo pen](https://codepen.io/andrewmmc/pen/jaNbYV) for more clarity.