# Rotating MarkerWithLabel using webkit Transform

Tags: javascript, google-maps, webkit

I'm using MarkerWithLabel to create markers on a Google map, but I want to be able to rotate the marker icon so I'm experimenting with webkit etc. transform operations.

So far I have the following:

```
    var pictureLabel = document.createElement("img");
    pictureLabel.src = "helloworld.gif";

    rotateImage( pictureLabel, 20 );

        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40,-10);

       marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
            position: myLatlng,
            labelContent: pictureLabel,
            icon: " "
        });

        marker.setMap(map);


function rotateImage( el, angle )
{
    rottext = "rotate(" + angle + "deg)";

    el.style.webkitTransform = '"' + rottext + '"';
    el.style.MozTransform = '"' + rottext + '"';
    el.style.msTransform = '"' + rottext + '"';
    el.style.OTransform = '"' + rottext + '"';
    el.style.transform = '"' + rottext + '"';
    el.style.transformOrigin = "50% 50%";
}
```

This produces no icon and I can't understand why. The problem must be in the function as, when I comment it out I get the icon displayed - just not rotated of course. Can anyone suggest what is wrong?

Comment: Related question: [rotate a .gif image on google maps api v3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38723573/rotate-a-gif-image-on-google-maps-api-v3)

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I am not using jQuery :(

Comment: I've done a bit of experimentation, with no luck:

  pictureLabel.setAttribute("id", "HelloImage");
                     rotateImage( "HelloImage", 50 );  


And in the function call, I have the first argument being "HelloImage"
and within, I have document.getElementById(el).style.webkitTransform = rottext; and for all the other calls therein.

It still doesn't work though.

Answer (score 0):

The assignment like this:

```
el.style.webkitTransform = '"' + rottext + '"';
```

is *invalid* since the proper format for `webkitTransform` property is `rotate(30deg)` but not `"rotate(30deg)"`

Having said that replace `rotateImage` functiion with:

```
function rotateImage(el, angle) {
    rottext = "rotate(" + angle + "deg)";

    el.style.webkitTransform = rottext;
    el.style.MozTransform = rottext;
    el.style.msTransform = rottext;
    el.style.OTransform = rottext;
    el.style.transform = rottext;
    el.style.transformOrigin = "50% 50%";
}
```

**Demo**

```js
function initMap() {
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(49.47805, -123.84716);
    var homeLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(49.47805, -123.84716);
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
        zoom: 12,
        center: latLng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var pictureLabel = document.createElement("img");
    pictureLabel.id = "customMarker1";
    pictureLabel.src = "https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/raw/master/markerwithlabel/examples/home.jpg";
    var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
        position: homeLatLng,
        map: map,
        draggable: true,
        raiseOnDrag: true,
        labelContent: pictureLabel,
        labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(50, 0),
        labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
    });
   var startAngle = 10;

    document.getElementById("btnRotate").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        var m = document.getElementById("customMarker1");
        rotateImage(m,startAngle);
        startAngle+=30;
    });
}
function log(h) {
    document.getElementById("log").innerHTML += h + "<br />";
}






function rotateImage(el, angle) {
    rottext = "rotate(" + angle + "deg)";

    el.style.webkitTransform = rottext;
    el.style.MozTransform = rottext;
    el.style.msTransform = rottext;
    el.style.OTransform = rottext;
    el.style.transform = rottext;
    el.style.transformOrigin = "50% 50%";
}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/master/markerwithlabel/src/markerwithlabel.js"></script>

<button id="btnRotate">Rotate</button>
 <div id="map_canvas" style="height: 400px; width: 100%;"></div>
 <div id="log"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you - I'm still having problems - it is now saying that el in the function call is null, and I don't see how that is. It must be something simple but I can't see what.

Comment: It looks like, outside the <head>, pictureLabel is going out of scope, even when I declare it as a var outside the initMap() function.

What I'm trying to do ultimately is do a setInterval() function call within the <body>; periodically, the rotation angle will be recalculated and this will show on the map. But I can't do that because when I try to do document.getElementById("customMarker1");   the returned ID is null - but if I use your method of calling it via a button click, it isn't null.

Comment: In my example the Id property is getting assigned for image element, see pictureLabel.id

Comment: Hi,
I've tried m = pictureLabel.id; rotateImage(m ,60);   but it seems that, in the body of the document, "rotateImage(m ,60);"  - this is even when pictureLabel is defined as global in the head.