# Google Maps API : Rotation with a custom marker Icon

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm working with Google Map Javascript API and I'm trying to create a custom Marker with a custom Icon which works with rotation,

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: this.map
});

marker.setIcon({
  url:"assets/icon/nav.png",
  //path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
  scale: 1,
  rotation: heading,
  scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35),
});
```

The rotation attribute is working with google.maps.SymbolPath.XXXX as the line commented in the code but not with a custom Icon Image like I wrote in my code,

So I'm asking is there any solution to make custom icon image rotate ? Or to create a google.maps.SymbolPath from an image ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [rotate a .gif image on google maps api v3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38723573/rotate-a-gif-image-on-google-maps-api-v3)

Answer (score 7):

1) No, as the **[Icon object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?#Icon)** doesn't have a `rotation` property, and

2) yes, you can, but for this, you need to use a **[Symbol object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?#Symbol)** and the [SVG path notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths). You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24426400/1238965) and [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/eLcNq/) for more info.

```
var symbol = {  
    path: "M0 0 H 90 V 90 H 0 L 0 0",
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: .5,
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    strokeWeight: 0,
    scale: .5,
    rotation: 45
}

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
    map: map,
    icon: symbol
});
```