# How can I rotate the customized icon of marker from vue2-google-map?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-maps

I know that the usage of path is the only way to rotate the marker based on documentation they have.
So I create my own PNG image for marker, but the problem I never succeed when overriding CSS of the marker.

I also tried to override the marker using DOM

```
document.querySelectorAll('img[src="@/assets/logo.png]')[0].parentNode.style.transform = "rotate(35deg)"
```

But it doesn't rotate the marker.

Any suggestion how can I rotate my customized marker?

Comment: You probably should not try to rotate the markers via CSS... The API supports rotation on Symbols and SVG markers.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49595076/google-maps-api-rotation-with-a-custom-marker-icon

Comment: possible duplicate of [rotate a .gif image on google maps api v3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38723573/rotate-a-gif-image-on-google-maps-api-v3)

Answer (score -1):

When we want to apply the css to a child component, then we need to make use of `v-deep` which helps in passing the css to the child.

For example:
Suppose we have a component like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <child></child>
  </div>
</template>
```

And in the child component we have a div with id `main`. Then in this case, we need to make use of `v-deep` on the parent component to style the main tag of child component.

```
::v-deep .main {
  ...style-goes-here
}
```

Comment: should I put the class="main" in <div>?

Comment: I am just giving an example, the `main` here should be the name of the class/id whose css style you want to update. Also, it will be good if you will share some code or will create a codepen or fiddle, so that we can understand better what you want to achieve.