# Javascript google maps api, marker not rotating icon

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

The marker just does not rotate, why??
I am using Google Maps Api V3
I am using a setInterval because my car is moving along the map
And needs to face the direction of the route (for now bearing is just pre set).

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    icon: {   
        url: "../includes/images/car.png",
        scale: 1,
        rotation: 0  
    },
    map: map,
    position: overview_path[0],
    optimized: false
});



var counter = 1;
setInterval(function() {
    debugger;
    var bearing = counter * 15;
    marker.setPosition(overview_path[counter]);
    var icon = marker.getIcon();
    icon.rotation = bearing;
    marker.setIcon(icon);
    setTimeout(function(){
        map.panTo({
            lat: marker.getPosition().lat(),
            lng: marker.getPosition().lng()
        })
    }, 2000)
    counter++;
}, 1000
```

Comment: Please just a hint.

Comment: `rotation` only applies to SVG Symbols.  Related question: [rotate a .gif image on google maps api v3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38723573/rotate-a-gif-image-on-google-maps-api-v3)

Comment: Thankyou very much!