# How to rotate google maps marker?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I use below code to create a marker with 190 degree rotation, but it doesn't work. Other icon options are working well, only rotation doesn't work.

```
createMapMarker(pos, map) {
    var iconUrl = 'assets/img/green_arrow.png'
    var iconScaledSize = new google.maps.Size(15, 15)
    var iconOrigin = new google.maps.Point(0,0)
    var iconAnchor = new google.maps.Point(7.5, 7.5)

    return new google.maps.Marker({
      position: pos,
      map: map,
      title: '',
      icon: {
        url: iconUrl,
        scaledSize: iconScaledSize,
        origin: iconOrigin,
        anchor:iconAnchor,
        rotation: 180,
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rotation is not a property of the [`Icon`](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker#Icon) Interface, it is only valid for the SVG [Symbol](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker#Symbol) Interface.

Either use an SVG Symbol for your icon or to rotate an image (jpeg, png, gif) use CSS (Related question: [rotate a .gif image on google maps api v3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38723573/rotate-a-gif-image-on-google-maps-api-v3))